# How to know AccountTeam in Salesforce is enabled or disabled through any API with Java?

Tags: java

**Java Code:** I have coded the following using REST API to connect to Salesforce. Following code is from the URL to get Schema or fields of AccountTeamMember (standard) object after establishing connection with salesforce org through RESTAPI:

```java
String schemaUrl = instanceurl + "/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/AccountTeamMember/describe";
log.info("schemeaUrl " + schemaUrl);
String responseString = "emptyschema";

Header printHeader = new BasicHeader("X-PrettyPrint", "1");
                
Header oAuthHeader = new BasicHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + accesstoken);
                
HttpGet schemaHttpGet = new HttpGet(schemaUrl);
                
schemaHttpGet.addHeader(oAuthHeader);
                
schemaHttpGet.addHeader(printHeader);
             
int count = 0;

response = httpClient.execute(schemaHttpGet);
log.info("after executing HTTPGet : " + response);
int iStatusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
log.info("iStatusCode : " + iStatusCode);
if (iStatusCode == 200) {
          
    HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
    log.warn("httpEntity : " + httpEntity);
    if (httpEntity != null) {

        log.info("before responseString " + responseString);
        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        log.info("after responseString " + responseString);
```

Here after running this code, I got all fields of AccountTeamMember (a standard object associated to the Account object) in Json format, if I keep AccountTeams enable, through RestAPI I am able to get all fields as json object and if disable then 404 status code.

So here is my question: Is there any other way to know AccountTeams is enabled for Account object other than this 404 status code and manually login to Salesforce org?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Metadata API** to get this information. In [AccountSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_accountsettings.htm) there is a field `enableAccountTeams` which Indicates whether account teams are enabled (true) or not (false).

You can refer the [Metadata API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickstart_java_sample.htm) which provides information on how to use Java Code to access Metadata API.

You can get this info using SOQL through **Tooling API**. Refer to the [Tooling API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm) for more details.

```
Select id, IsAccountTeamsEnabled From AccountSettings
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Could you please tell me how can i get accountsettings fields from soql  I worte this query in developer console                    
 Select id,name, (Select fields(all) From AccountSettings limit 10) From Account

Comment: @AkhilUmap - Please find my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you once again for your help! I am new to salesforce would you please suggest me how to learn salesforce from scratch and master it with all APIS

Comment: @AkhilUmap - [Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/career-path) is a good start for you. Please create an account and start learning.

Comment: Thank you so much!!